how to connect to fabric lakhouse using duckdb from databricks premium workspace?
how can I access data from fabric datalake from databricks using duckdb? I am using databricks premium workspace and can read and wite using spark. But when trying to connect through duck db I am getting the below error (I am not using any SPN or access key for duckdb client):

IOException: IO Error: AzureBlobStorageFileSystem could not open file: 'abfss://demo@onelake.dfs.fabric.microsoft.com/Lakehouse.Lakehouse/Files/20180402040501.CSV', unknown error occurred, this could mean the credentials used were wrong. Original error message: 'Fail to get a new connection for: https://demo@onelake.blob.fabric.microsoft.com. Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)'


provide the code you are using to access using duck db.

@JayashankarGS  this is the code. I am not able to use any access keys since apart from the abfss path I am not getting any SAS keys.
import duckdb
raw=duckdb.sql('''select * from  read_csv('abfss://demo@onelake.dfs.fabric.microsoft.com/Lakehouse.Lakehouse/Files/20180402040501.CSV')''')

Is there a specific requirement why are you loading a csv file, in duckdb, on databricks premium workspace? If you can use spark, use that?

Hi @Jon excellent question. Actually, I am trying to bench mark the performance of duckdb. Since my dataset is medium size, I want to experiment with newer engines. I am just wondering (and not finding any solid document) if the credential passover works only for spark engine in databricks or any other engines can be made to do that?

i guess integration of lakehouse with databricks is only thorugh enabling credential pass through with spark only.

Try mounting the location and accessing it with a local filesystem path. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dbfs/mounts

According to this documentation the only way to integrate lakehouse with databricks is by enabling credential passthrough, that too in spark context like
spark.read and dbutils.fs.ls.
I have tried to mount the path that too got me error.
So, at last the only possible way is to copy the data to temporary file and read it in duckdb.
Here is the code.
Copy to fab_tmp.csv
dbutils.fs.cp("abfss://8e2cff3b-xx-yyy-uuuuab0eccda54@msit-onelake.dfs.fabric.microsoft.com/d19xxx-yyyyy-r-7399/Files/bulk.csv","fab_tmp.csv")

Read the file.
import duckdb 
raw=duckdb.sql('''select * from read_csv('/dbfs/fab_tmp.csv')''')
display(raw)

Output:

when it comes to performance i would suggest you to use spark since the databricks is configured the authentications correctly in spark context.

Thanks a lot. I am also thinking like this.


From where you are getting the ADLS gen2 storage links which is used in onelake to mount? I can only see the abfss path of my data lake.


I have around 110 gb of data so if I want to copy it in temp in data bricks that means I am re duplicating data? Can mounting the onelake data as a volume in databricks helps?



I have tried to mount the abfss link but no success. If you are having such large data and need use databricks the efficient way is using spark engine to read. Duckdb is not feasible in this environment.
